# How to splice the value from arrays in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have declared an array as  `var user_profile = [];` and I have already some pushed data in arrayList which contains :

```
[  
   {  
      "assessmentType":"PRE",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"appeal",
      "assessAmount":"445",
      "assessPenalty":"",
      "assessTotal":445
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"PRE",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"appeal",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"PRE",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"445",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"PRE",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"PRE",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-13",
      "assessAmount":"2075-09-03",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"PRE",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-13",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"PRE",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-03",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"PRE",
      "assessCatId":1,
      "assessReason":"A",
      "assessAmount":"1",
      "assessPenalty":"2",
      "assessTotal":3
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"PRE",
      "assessCatId":2,
      "assessReason":"B",
      "assessAmount":"3",
      "assessPenalty":"40",
      "assessTotal":43
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"PRE",
      "assessCatId":3,
      "assessReason":"C",
      "assessAmount":"5",
      "assessPenalty":"6",
      "assessTotal":11
   }
]
```

In those list of arrays i need to remove the data whose **assessCatId==0**. So I tried to splice using

```
$.each(user_profile, function(i) {
  if (user_profile[i].assessCatId == 0) {
    user_profile.splice(i, 1);
  }
});
```

But it is not working.It is showing me error as:

[image]

Or I mean to say I just need the data in arrayList whose `assessCatId==1 or 2 or 3.` How to filter this arrayList and remove those data from arrayList?

Comment: hey you should take the index and splice it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to mutate (eg `splice`) an array *while* you're iterating over it - it will result in very unintuitive behavior. For example, after the first element gets removed, further iterations' `i` will refer the index that the element being iterated over *used* to be at, not the index that the element is at in the new mutated array - resulting in `undefined` problems near the end, and in incorrect indicies being removed.

A simple `.filter` would be a better option here, no need for jQuery:

```js
const input=[{"assessmentType":"PRE","assessCatId":0,"assessReason":"appeal","assessAmount":"445","assessPenalty":"","assessTotal":445},{"assessmentType":"PRE","assessCatId":0,"assessReason":"appeal","assessTotal":null},{"assessmentType":"PRE","assessCatId":0,"assessReason":"445","assessTotal":null},{"assessmentType":"PRE","assessCatId":0,"assessReason":"","assessTotal":null},{"assessmentType":"PRE","assessCatId":0,"assessReason":"2075-09-13","assessAmount":"2075-09-03","assessTotal":null},{"assessmentType":"PRE","assessCatId":0,"assessReason":"2075-09-13","assessTotal":null},{"assessmentType":"PRE","assessCatId":0,"assessReason":"2075-09-03","assessTotal":null},{"assessmentType":"PRE","assessCatId":1,"assessReason":"A","assessAmount":"1","assessPenalty":"2","assessTotal":3},{"assessmentType":"PRE","assessCatId":2,"assessReason":"B","assessAmount":"3","assessPenalty":"40","assessTotal":43},{"assessmentType":"PRE","assessCatId":3,"assessReason":"C","assessAmount":"5","assessPenalty":"6","assessTotal":11}]

const output = input.filter(({ assessCatId }) => assessCatId != 0);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: `filter` requires significantly less code (less surface area for bugs) and is much more intuitive than `splice` for this situation - it's definitely preferable to the alternative.

Comment: @CertainPerformance what if i need to add condition to check both condition assesscatId=0 and  assessReason== empty.

Comment: @ashwin Then extract both properties: `({ assessCatId, assessReason }) => assessCatId != 0 || assessReason != 'empty')` or something of the sort

Comment: @CertainPerformance the way u said me to filter assessReason is not working .Please help me

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you're looking for, what sort of output are you expecting? Note that you currently do not have any `assessReason` properties which are `'empty'` in the input array